# Force use old flash player version

Tags: flash

First, I want to say that I'm not a flash developer at all. I don't know much about it.
But I have a problem with a *swf file. It works with flash player 10.3.183.11 but not anymore with 11.2.202.235. How can we force the user to use an old flash version to play the .swf?

Answer (score 0):

No way. There is only one instance of flash player which works on browser at one time. Did you try to run your swf file under debug player? I think it could help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't tried the flash debugger, that's a good idea. I will check it out.

Comment: I installed the flash debugger, but I have nothing news (no trace, no error,etc...) looks nothing happend. I installed flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.exe after uninstalled the standard and tested jn firefox.

Comment: The flash is not really broke, I means it doesn't crash but it doesn't have the same behavior than before.

Comment: hmm, then you can fix it only using sources of this swf.

Answer (score 0):

you can run multiple version of flash in google chrome and using the chrome://plugins/
you can enable and disable the different versions so thus "use the one u like to do
what you wanna do 'assuming its supported"